# Scala loop over sequence of user defined classes

Tags: scala, seq

I have a function which receives a sequence of two user defined classes:

```
tags: Seq[(tag, pattern)]
```

I want to access each element of sequence then access to fields belonging to tag and pattern from that element. I am able to print all sequence lines using:

```
for(i <- tags)
  {
    println("Tags for i are " + i)
  }
```

But how can I access tag and pattern from i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for ((t, p) <- tags) {
  println(s"Tag: $t Pattern: $p")
}
```

Comment: it is worth mentioning for completeness that you can access unnamed elements for a tuple with `i._1`, `i._2` etc.